How to ensure consistent browser positioning measurements
I have a function that loops through a javascript array/object, adds some spans to the DOM, measures their positions and returns the measurements.
Example code below, but my question isn't really about the code.
99% of the time these measurements are accurate, but not always.  Sometimes the positioning will be significantly off.
Usually when they are off, running the function again will resolve it, but it has never happened to me, only other users and I am not sure what could be happening.
My only guesses are, maybe the user is resizing the browser window?  Or doing something else that is affecting it?  I am a bit at a loss.
So my question is, is there a standard way to prevent this sort of thing?
Could there be something I am missing?  There are no animations or anything happening.  Just placing the text and measuring.
To maybe lock down the browser so measurements cannot get disrupted? Or am I off track on that thinking?
EXAMPLE
HTML
<div style="position:absolute;width:400px;display:flex" id="measurecontainer"></div>
JAVASCRIPT
$( document ).ready(function() {


//example text
var tss = {};
tss[1] = {};
 Object.assign(tss[1], {word: 'Test One',id: 1});


tss[2] = {};
 Object.assign(tss[2], {word: 'Test Two',id:2});


tss[3] = {};
 Object.assign(tss[3], {word: 'Test Three',id: 3});




function measure_text(tss) {


var measurements = {};



var html = '';

for (const key in tss) {
  if (tss.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const item = tss[key];
     html += '<span style="margin:5px;padding:5px" id="'+item.id+'" class="measurethese" id="'+item.id+'">'+item.word+'</span>';
}
}


jQuery('#measurecontainer').html(html);


//measure each span
$('.measurethese').each(function(index, value) {

var elementid = jQuery(this).attr('id');

var innerelement = document.getElementById(elementid);
var positionInfo = innerelement.getBoundingClientRect();

var outerelement = document.getElementById('measurecontainer');
var outerpositionInfo = outerelement.getBoundingClientRect();

var positiontop = positionInfo.top - outerpositionInfo.top;
var positionleft = positionInfo.left - outerpositionInfo.left;

console.log('WORD ID '+elementid);
console.log('Position Top '+positiontop);
console.log('Position Left '+positionleft);

});


}



measure_text(tss);


});```


When the positioning is returned incorrectly, what is being returned? A larger or smaller value than you expected? Is there any pattern to this incorrect value such as always being larger or smaller than expected? Just trying to get an idea of what could be happening.

Does your code have anything which would induce a temporary shifting of the elements or make changes in DOM width / height? For example, tooltips, AJAX insertion of elements while hovering over something, dropdowns showing up after a certain user action (hover, click, etc) occurs, and so on?

@DanielBlack It seems when it happens lately, it is larger rather than smaller. i.e. my example today had the left positioning about 100px farther than it should have been.  And in that case, after the report, I just loaded the same example and re-ran the function and it came out as it should have.  But in the recent past, it always seems to be a value larger.

@FiddlingAway Maybe....  When the actual measurement function runs, no.  BUT, there is also a preview function that does include animations and it runs in the same container.  When the measurement function is run, however, an overlay appears letting the user know NOT to resize or refresh, so I am not sure how they would be able to trigger the preview function while it is measuring.  The overlay was my attempt at "locking things down" to try to prevent any inadvertent resizing or manipulation.  But for the measurement function itself, it is static.
